# How to write ruby function inside shopify liquid?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shopify

Is there a way to write a custom function in ruby and call it inside the shopify liquid theme?
I am really very new with both ruby and shopify, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. You cannot write any Ruby scripting inside your Shopify Liquid templates. The scripting languages you can use include Javascript and Liquid.

Liquid is excellent at pulling data from Shopify that can be rendered using HTML, made to look good with CSS, and have some dynamic behaviour added with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can write ruby in a Shopify Shopify Plus store using the scripts app, that affects checkout (and by extension, values in the cart).

If you're using Shopify Plus then you have access to this app: [Script Editor](https://apps.shopify.com/script-editor)

Which will enable you to have some fun with Ruby.  I haven't pushed the limits with it but we've used in projects.